# Intermittent ComboBox issues

Tags: gridview, extjs, combobox

I'm using ExtJS 4.2.1.883 to build a grid with RowEditing capabilities. I've been struggling with this for a few days, even though I do read the documentation and search the Web extensively.

The problem at hand: one of the columns in my grid is a ComboBox defined like so:

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.editor.MyComboBox', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias:  'widget.my-combo-box',

    triggerAction: 'all',
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'ShortName',
    valueField: 'Identity',
    store: Ext.create('myapp.store.business.MyStore'),

    editable: false,
    forceSelection: true,
    emptyText: 'Select an item...',
    multiSelect: false
});
```

Its corresponding store extends `Ext.data.Store` and has `autoLoad: true`. It is backed by a very simple model that only has three `type: 'string'` fields and has the identity field set as `idProperty: 'Identity'`.

Now, when I double-click a record in the grid to edit, **intermittently the combo field becomes empty** (although it had a value in it prior to double-click); worse yet, the combo would not open after that. Even if I close and then reopen the editor. I say intermittently, because I was unable to reproduce this behaviour reliably. Sometimes it just does. Sometimes it does not, no matter how many times I summon row editing. Also note that the data coming from the store does not change, it's a stable dataset migrated for testing purposes from a previous version of the system.

Yesterday I saw another event that seemed like a bug: **the first entry in the combo was duplicated**. I rechecked the backend to make sure it only sends one instance of the record. Today, after simply reloading the Web UI of the application, I cannot reproduce this, even though the code didn't change overnight.

[Edit] There are no errors or warnings in my Chrome console.

**Is there a valid reason for such behaviour on the part of ComboBox? How do I make it behave properly?**

I'd also like to know if moving to a later version of ExtJS 4 would be wise, bug-wise. I've had it with the version I'm currently using, mostly for being unable to follow the development schedule due to all the inconsistencies and workarounds and the sheer size of the thing (by comparison, Common Lisp I use for backend seems like a nineteenth century wooden toy and it mostly just works), but I'm also reluctant to switch even minor versions mid-project, let alone switch frameworks.

Comment: the line I found strange is the store definition, I always set the store like `store: 'business.MyStore'`, can you try that?

Comment: and include the store in the stores array of your controller

Comment: I made the change you suggested. Will see if the the problem comes back and report here. Why the explicit instantiation? I have read in two places (a book on ExtJs and in a third-party tutorial on the Web) that sharing a store may have undesired effects for controls that filter their contents, because the filtering is done by the store.  I'd venture that instantiation (maybe, not sure) might be better done in initComponent rather than in the declaration, but for the fact that the combo did work when using Ext.create, although, as I said, not very reliably...

Comment: hm, I have many sites with a combobox editor where the store is shared and never had any problems

Comment: @Jan S, do you also use filtering? Like `typeAhead: true` and/or `editable: true`? http://skirtlesden.com/articles/extjs-comboboxes-part-2 says it shouldn't work ("Sharing Stores Between ComboBoxes") and it was consistent with my experience when I first used a shared store (I think I was trying to create a picker with a combo at that time instead of using the combo directly, but it shouldn't make any difference.)

Comment: Anyway, it would appear that this change fixes the strange behaviour. At least for now. :-) Would you care to post your suggestion as an answer, so I could accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set the store as a string like:

```
store: 'business.MyStore'
```

and add the store to the controllers store array.
I also had options like editable ore typeAhead enabled. the store is only filtered as long as you are in edit mode as soon as you leave edit the store is unfiltered again.